# ListBox ScrollBar with different line colors on it

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, scrollbar

I want to customize my ListBox `vertical ScrollBar` to show current selected item position with blue mark like we have in VS editor and also want to `show background color of listboxitem` on `vertical scrollbar` line.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to re-template the ScrollBar and add code that draws the colors.
Cannot give you a full code example as it would take me hours (or more) do complete the code

Comment: Yes but you can give me small sample. How I can get exact location on scrollbar to draw colors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your custom ScrollViewer:

```
public class MyScrollViewer : ScrollViewer
{
    static MyScrollViewer()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyScrollViewer), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyScrollViewer)));
    }


}
```

with its XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyScrollViewer}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyScrollViewer}">
                <Grid>
                    <ScrollContentPresenter />
                    <local:MyScrollBar Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Orientation="Horizontal" Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                             Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" 
                             Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" />

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And here is the custom ScrollBar used by the ScrollViewer:

```
public class MyScrollBar : ScrollBar
{
    static MyScrollBar()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyScrollBar), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyScrollBar)));
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        var canvas = Template.FindName("PART_Canvas", this) as Canvas;

        if (canvas != null)
        {
            //draw something onto the canvas
            Line myLine = new Line();

            myLine.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;

            myLine.X1 = 100;
            myLine.X2 = 140;  
            myLine.Y1 = 200;
            myLine.Y2 = 200;

            myLine.StrokeThickness = 1;

            canvas.Children.Add(myLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Also with XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyScrollBar}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyScrollBar}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="18"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.00001*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="18"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="3" CornerRadius="2" Background="Transparent" />
                        <RepeatButton  Grid.Column="0" Width="18" Command="ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand" Content="M 4 0 L 4 8 L 0 4 Z" />
                        <Canvas x:Name="PART_Canvas" Grid.Column="1" />
                        <RepeatButton Grid.Column="2"  Width="18" Command="ScrollBar.LineRightCommand" Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 0 8 Z"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And here is the Windows using this control:

```
<Window x:Class="VSScroller.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VSScroller"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <local:MyScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Background="Yellow">
        <TextBlock>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's <LineBreak/>
                   standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer <LineBreak/>
            took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a <LineBreak/>
                   type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, <LineBreak/>
            but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining 
                   essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with <LineBreak/>
            the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, <LineBreak/>
                   and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus <LineBreak/>
            PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</TextBlock>
    </local:MyScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: And now you add custom logic to draw the colors onto the ScrollBar canvas

Comment: Thank you bidy.. But still my question is how I can find exact location on ScrollBar to draw BackGround Color??

Comment: No sure if I really understand the question. Are you asking for an algorithm for placing your blue mark?

Comment: No not the algorithm.. But how would I get the `position on ScrollBar to draw BackgroundColor of ListBoxItem onto ScrollBar`??

Comment: Well, I don't know your code. But you would draw the marks (colors) on the canvas. Get the height (or Width) of the canvas (.ActualHeight). Let's say your LIstBox has 10 Items and the 5. is the one you want to mark on the Scrollbar, you mark the middle of the canvas.

Comment: Thanks a lottt bidy this is working absolutely fine... Got the results what I wanted..

Answer (score 0):

As bidy said, retemplate the ScrollBar to customise. Here is a good example of custom scrollbar that outlines the main components etc: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85896/WPF-Customize-your-Application-with-Styles-and-C

Comment: Yes Naadof.. But I need a brief idea about how i can implement this feature?.. How I can get exact location of ListBoxItem on vertical scrollbar and paint that area with corresponding ListBoxItem's background brush?